# How to implement UIProgressView to display the progress of a method of another class?

Tags: ios6, automatic-ref-counting, uiprogressview

I've been reading about delegate pattern. But answers and examples for this simple work are explained too bad and report many erros, expecially 'cause they are olds and I want to develop it in iOS6 with ARC and Storyboard.

(a class "`myClass`" that contain my method "`myMethod`")

(a `UIViewController` "`myVC`" with `UIProgressView` "`myProgressView`" where i call :
`[myClass myMethod]` in a background thread and I can show progress in main thread.

Can anyone explains in a simply code what i mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google on iOS delegate tutorial and i'm sure it'll come up with something

Comment: Sorry sir, my problem it's about showing the update of a uiprogressview handling thread in background. Thanks for "keyword" but it's not enough!

Comment: There plenty dcumentation online on background worker threads to keep your app responsible, too.we can help, but you need to do a little wrk yourself.

Comment: Perhaps GDC is what you are looking for: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12574522/is-there-any-good-tutorial-about-gcd-grand-central-dsipatch